# How to remove header in tableofcontents and make a blank space between "chapter" and name of chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I use this code to make a document. How can I remove header in tableofcontents, but keep header document and make a blank space between "chapter" and name of chapter?
My code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{float}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{{\it \chaptername\,\thechapter.\  #1}}{}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\it \thesection.\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]%
{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\cfoot{}
\sloppy

\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\apptocmd{\appendix}
{\addtocontents{toc}{%  
        \protect\addtolength\protect\cftchapnumwidth{-\mylength}%
        \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Something ~}%
        \protect\settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\protect\cftchappresnum\protect\cftchapaftersnum}%
        \protect\addtolength\protect\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}}%
}{}{}

\newlength\mylength
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
\settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    ,unicode,bookmarksnumbered
}

%\usepackage[linkcolor=blue,colorlinks=true,unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Chapter one}
    \section{Something}
    \lipsum[1-5]
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \lipsum[6-10]
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \lipsum[11-15]
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        
        \section{Something}
        \lipsum[6-10]
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \lipsum[11-15]
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
        \chapter{Chapter}   
        \section{Something}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\pagestyle{empty}` before  `\tableofcontents`, and `\pagestyle{fancy}` afterwards. As to the spacing between chapter and the chaptername, add a qua or a half quad in  `\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}`:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tasks}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usepackage{float}
    \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}%

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
    {\markboth{{\it \chaptername\,\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}

    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
    {\markright{\it \thesection.\ #1}}
    \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\thepage}]%
    {\fancyplain{}{\rightmark}}
    \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\leftmark}]%
    {\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
    \cfoot{}
    \sloppy

    \usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
    \usepackage{tocloft}

    \apptocmd{\appendix}
    {\addtocontents{toc}{%
            \protect\addtolength\protect\cftchapnumwidth{-\mylength}%
            \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Something ~}%
            \protect\settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\protect\cftchappresnum\protect\cftchapaftersnum}%
            \protect\addtolength\protect\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}}%
    }{}{}

    \newlength\mylength
    \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.\quad}

    \renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter~}
    \settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
    \addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        ,unicode,bookmarksnumbered
    }
    %\usepackage[linkcolor=blue,colorlinks=true,unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
        \tableofcontents

    \pagestyle{fancy}
        \chapter{Chapter one}
        \section{Something}
        \lipsum[1-5]
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \lipsum[6-10]
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \lipsum[11-15]
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
                \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}

            \section{Something}
            \lipsum[6-10]
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \lipsum[11-15]
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}
            \chapter{Chapter}
            \section{Something}

    \end{document}
```

[image]